# illegala argument exception : illegal argument in query

Tags: android, json, android-maps-v2

Here posting error related code and logs ,issue is trying display places using map api v2 ,while sending data to url getting this exception ,so i think problem in sending request but i got JSON data [like this](https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.21544712,81.32074942&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=food%7Cbar%7Cclub&key=AIzaSyDd0nvZVyPxj10fWbgD4t_n_KG_TDKDl60) help me.

```
    10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal character in query at index 128: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.21544712,81.32074942&radius=1000&sensor=true&types=food|bar|club&key=something
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at java.net.URI.create(URI.java:727)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet.<init>(HttpGet.java:75)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at com.tukutane.StartActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:220)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at com.tukutane.StartActivity$GetPlaces.doInBackground(StartActivity.java:1)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
10-03 19:45:41.422: W/System.err(27832):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
10-03 19:45:41.432: W/System.err(27832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
10-03 19:45:41.432: W/System.err(27832):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
10-03 19:45:41.432: W/System.err(27832):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
```

code:

```
    // build places query string
                    String placesSearchStr = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?"
                            + "location="
                            + mCurrentLocation.getLatitude()
                            + ","
                            + mCurrentLocation.getLongitude()
                            + "&radius=1000&sensor=true"
                            + "&types=food|bar|club"
                            + "&key=xxxxxxxx";
                    // execute query
                    new GetPlaces().execute(placesSearchStr);
        // Move the camera instantly to User location with a zoom of 12.
        googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(
                USER_LOCATION, 12));

        // Zoom in, animating the camera.
        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(10), 2000, null);
```

Comment: You really don't want to give away your API key.  I've edited it out.

Comment: it is okay dude,not an issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Illegal character in query at index 128: ...

This means you have an illegal character in your string. In your case, it's a pipe (`|`). You need to url encode the character as `%7C`. If you visit the link you posted, you can see that's the way it's displayed there as well.

You can do this manually or with `URLEncoder`:

```
+ "&types=food%7Cbar%7Cclub"
```

or

```
+ "&types=" + URLEncoder.encode("food|bar|club", "utf-8")
```

Comment: sorry ,Not getting .it is provided by developer site,okay how to encode it.?

Comment: Hey but with your tip i am not getting JSON response?

Comment: Hmm. Works on my end. First result is "Dwarika Restaurant".

Comment: Getting REQUEST DENIED message

Comment: That sounds like a separate issue, to be honest. Make sure your url is correct, including the API key. If you still can't get it, you might consider searching for that error or asking another question.

Comment: https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=21.21544712,81.32074942&radius=1000&sensor=true%26types%3Dfood%7Cbar%7Cclub&key=AIzaSyDd0nvZVyPxj10fWbgD4t_n_KG_TDKDl60

Comment: previously i am getting JSONdata ,now i am not getting then how can it related to another question?But thanks for your time and help..

Comment: Check my edit. It was encoding the `&` and `=` along with the pipes.

Comment: Your edit works for me ,now getting data ,i am looking in to that URlEncoder also,Now you deserves my accept mark..TQ TQ